# how to properly parse String containing custom data (Semantic Versioning data)?

Tags: string, flutter, parsing, dart, integer

```
{
    "android_version": "1.0.0",
    "ios_version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I have this json data which i want to parse. Parsing json is easy. But i cannot implement this method:

```
class AppVersion {
  int level1;
  int level2;
  int level3;

  AppVersion(this.level1, this.level2, this.level3);

  factory AppVersion.fromString(String text){
    // TODO: implement parsing String "X.X.X" into 3 integers
    return AppVersion(1, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special package for this purpose:
https://pub.dev/packages/version

```
  Version currentVersion = Version(1, 0, 3);
  Version latestVersion = Version.parse("2.1.0");

  if (latestVersion > currentVersion) {
    print("Update is available");
  }
```